# How to use sql defined functions as fields?

Tags: c#, sql, reserved-words

I am creating tables in Sql Management Studio 2012 using SQL. How do I make fields or columns with names that are already defined in Sql Server e.g User_ID, User_Name. I want to use them as fields in my tables.

[image: Code]

Table definition from [Duplicate Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30152407/how-to-sql-defined-fucntion-as-fields-e-g-user-id-int-sql-when-creating-tables):

```
create table Ticket(
  Ticket_Id varchar(10) not null,
  TicketType_Id varchar(3) not null,
  Ticket_PurchaseDate DateTime null,
  LottoDraw_Id int null,
  User_Id int null,
  Ticket_IsWinner bit null
  Primary Key(Ticket_Id,TicketType_Id)
)
```

Comment: Please post your code as text not a link to an image

Comment: Use SQLDataAdapter to load SQL Select query into a DataTable.  Fields in DataTable can be indexed either by index number or by indexed by string name which is the SQL Field name.

Comment: You can escape keywords using by surrounding them with square brackets e.g. `[name]`.

Comment: One way is to follow T I's suggestion, and another is simply not to do it. there is a reason why reserved words are reserved. [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30131409/is-there-a-way-to-not-use-square-brackets-in-sql-server/30132058)

Comment: None of those are [reserved words](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx). The code you posted works fine without any escaping.

Comment: Possibly OP was unnerved by the syntax highlighting in the pasted image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warp the column name like in brackets [ ]  ... such as

```
create table Ticket(
  Ticket_Id varchar(10) not null,
  TicketType_Id varchar(3) not null,
  Ticket_PurchaseDate DateTime null,
  LottoDraw_Id int null,
  [User_Id] int null,
  Ticket_IsWinner bit null
  Primary Key(Ticket_Id,TicketType_Id)
)
```

Comment: While this answers the question exactly, I would recommend avoiding this kind of naming convention in sql. I've already linked my reasons in a comment to the question, so I won't do it again here.