# How to Sql defined function as columns e.g User_Id int when creating tables

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm creating tables in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio using SQL, how do I make columns or columns with names that are already defined in SQL Server e.g `User_ID`, `User_Name`, I want to use these as fields in my tables

```
create table Ticket
(
     Ticket_Id varchar(10) not null,
     TicketType_Id varchar(3) not null,
     Ticket_PurchaseDate DateTime null,
     LottoDraw_Id int null,
     User_Id int null,
     Ticket_IsWinner bit null

     Primary Key(Ticket_Id, TicketType_Id)
)
```

Comment: Your code works fine:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e3f1a.

Comment: This has to be the question with the most unrelated tags I've seen in the last month. If it's sql server, what does it have to do with mysql and oracle, and how the hell did you get c# involved here?

Comment: `t-i` has answered your question in a comment in your previous post of this question. Please don't post duplicates, rather, spend time editing your question to provide the information needed in order to answer it.