# Select columns from Two Tables along with 'Like' statement

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, where-clause

I'm writing a Search Functionality for my website and I need to scan two tables and select rows which contain a specific string that I send (using LIKE). I wrote this but it doesn't send back anything.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From Table1, Table2 where Name LIKE '" + searchText + "%' OR Table2 where Name LIKE '" + searchText + "%'", con);
```

Basically get all rows from BOTH tables having rows similar to the string I send. Scan both table's columns for a specific string I send using 'LIKE'

**COLUMN NAMES** are different :)

Is this the proper way to do this?

Comment: No. This is not the right way

Comment: Seems not a valid SQL. You try to use multiple table in your `WHERE` clause. Which columns do you think you will get at the end? On which table?

Comment: @Raj please enlighten me

Comment: Your SQL is invalid. Write the SQL correctly, test in SSMS and then put it over here

Comment: assuming both table structure are same, I think what you are looking for is this `"Select * From Table1 WHERE Name LIKE '" + searchText + "%'
UNION ALL

Select * From Table2 where Name LIKE '" + searchText + "%'"`

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected output. what you are doing is a cross join. not sure if that is what you want

Comment: If both tables have the same structure, whats the point of having 2 tables?

Comment: Exactly, Serv. Also: Please try to avoid naming columns "Name" or the like, that's bad practice. If you do use column names like "Name", "Date" etc, enclose them in brackets in sql queries: "... WHERE [Table1].[Name] LIKE...".

Comment: @serv - In a few scenarios like History table, there can be tables with similar structure. I am not sure in this case though

Comment: @ughai history tables usually have a few more columns then source tables such as the date the record went to history and so on...

Comment: @Serv both tables don't have the same column names

Comment: @LocEngineer I couldn't agree more. In fact, just a few days ago I've wrote [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30131409/is-there-a-way-to-not-use-square-brackets-in-sql-server/30132058#30132058) that specifies the method I use to avoid using reserved words and function names in sql. I admit, this is a bit of self promoting, but the main reason I've linked it is because I truly believe this method is the best naming convention for database objecs.

Comment: @LocEngineer guys I added that name on purpose so that it's clear for the good lads on Stack :) The column names were properly named

Comment: @ZoharPeled  guys I added that name on purpose so that it's clear for the good lads on Stack :) The column names were properly named

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems in your code.

The first in severity is the fact that you use string concatenation instead of [parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738521%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).
This makes your code very vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks.](https://xkcd.com/327/)

The second one is that your SQL is simply wrong.
You are using an implicit join without any join condition.
This makes a [cross join](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), but I'm not sure that this is what you want.
Always use explicit joins. i.e `from t1 inner join t2 on(t1.id = t2.id)`.
Implicit joins are out of style for more then 20 years now.
Read [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/78225/using-join-keyword-or-not) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins) for some more information about the differences between implicit and explicit joins

I won't give you an SQL suggestion since it's not very clear what is the desired outcome, but you have to take the points I made into consideration, if you want to write a good code.

**update**
Based on your comments, you can probably do something like this:

```
declare @Name varchar(10)='as'

SELECT Table1.*, Table2.*
FROM (
    SELECT t1_Id As Id, 1 As TableNumber
    FROM Table1 
    WHERE t1_Name LIKE @Name+'%'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t2_Id as Id, 2 As TableNumber
    FROM Table2 
    WHERE t2_Name LIKE @Name+'%'
) SearchResults
LEFT JOIN Table1 ON(t1_Id = Id AND TableNumber = 1)
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON(t2_Id = Id AND TableNumber = 2)
```

[see sql fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a2a07/9)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions mate :) I want to get ALL data from both the tables (Column names could be different) IF they contain similar data to the string I send. I assume that is done using LIKE.

Comment: So if I send "John", the query should return "John Skully" from table1 and also "John Doolittle" from table2 :) And every other John for that matter. I just want to scan two tables at once and avoid two queries

Comment: Do you have anything in common between these 2 tables that you can use for a join?

Comment: Do they have columns with unique values (like an Id column)?

Comment: Yes they do. Both of them has a 'id' column :)

Answer (score 2):

If you confirm that both tables have the same columns, you can use this query;

```
Select * From Table1
where Name LIKE '" + searchText + "%' 
UNION ALL
Select * From Table2 
where Name LIKE '" + searchText + "%'
```

Comment: Thats exactly, what I thought OP needs. Without expected output, it's hard to confirm if this is correct or not.

Comment: Downvote reasons: 1: What if the tables column doesn't match? you will get an exception. 2: still letting little booby tables jump in...

Comment: Sorry the column names are different

Comment: @ZoharPeled I did mention if the columns are identical, right? Have you even read the answer before?

Comment: @Nadeem_MK: Sorry, I don't know how I've missed that. However, little bobby tables is still a valid reason for a downvote in my eyes.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From Table1 tbl1, Table2 tbl2 where tbl1.Name LIKE '" + searchText + "%' OR tbl2.Name LIKE '" + searchText + "%'", con);
```

Comment: This will give a [cross join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join), so if there are 5 results from `Table1` and 5 results from `Table2` then 25 rows will be returned.  This is almost certainly not the correct result.