# Why some rows can be inserted into and some cannot?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, vb.net

When I use the Cashier table or some other tables that have small amounts of records the process proceeds and table is inserted into the external database. But when I change the cashier into the transaction database (400k+ records), Visual Studio reports an error near "Transaction" Help would be appreciated thanks.

Cashier Database (working)

```
Dim query As String = "select * into MyDatabase2.dbo.Cashier from bos_primary_db.dbo.Cashier"
```

Transaction Database (not working)

```
Dim query As String = "select * into MyDatabase2.dbo.Transaction from bos_primary_db.dbo.Transaction"
```

This is the error message:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Transaction'

Comment: make sure the table dbo.transaction exists in bos_primary_db

Comment: It does exist, but it's still getting that error.

Comment: and what error is it exactly

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Transaction'.

Comment: then @Zohar is right

Comment: @JamesZ: What's the point of putting a question on hold when it's already have an accepted answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is probably because `Transaction` is a reserved word in SQL.
Depending on your RDBMS (that you didn't specify), there are ways to "escape" it:
for **Sql Server**, you should wrap reserved words in square brackets:

```
select * into MyDatabase2.dbo.[Transaction] from bos_primary_db.dbo.[Transaction]
```

For **MySql** you should use an apostrophe:

```
select * into MyDatabase2.dbo.`Transaction` from bos_primary_db.dbo.`Transaction`
```

For **Oracle** you should use double quotes:

```
select * into MyDatabase2.dbo."Transaction" from bos_primary_db.dbo."Transaction"
```

**Note:** You should always try to avoid using reserved words. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30132058/3094533) describes my favorite way of do it.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please consider editing your question to include the relevant RDBMS tag for future users that might have the same problem.