# In SQL Server what's the difference between selecting a column as Year and [Year]?

Tags: sql-server

Do we add '[]' just to differentiate the system defined keyword from our own ... ? Or is there any other reason behind using '[]'? Thanks!

Comment: The use of square brackets in t-sql is to allow you to use reserved words as object names or aliases. However, I would recommend not using reserved words to begin with.

Comment: Have a read of this [`Database Identifider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The use of square brackets in t-sql is to allow you to use reserved words as object names or aliases.
However, I would recommend not using reserved words to begin with.
[Here is my prefered method of avoiding the use of reserved words.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30132058/3094533)

Comment: I guess we cannot avoid using [] if in our object relational model the table column is mapped to a property which is a reserved keyword in sql.

Comment: I am not an ORM expert, but I do believe you should be able to map a property to a column with a different name in most ORMs. Otherwise you would not need mappings at all...

Answer (score 0):

say you want to name your table **my table**  only way to do this is to put it like so: [my table] . Same principle applies for other database objects.

```
create table [my table] (
column1 varchar(30), column2 varchar(50))
```