# Diffrence between these select queries

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT cust_email  FROM  customer AS c WHERE c.cust_email="pankaj@yahoo.com"
SELECT cust_email  FROM  customer  WHERE cust_email="pankaj@yahoo.com"
```

I have  these 2 sql queries which perform same operation ,my question is what is the use of giving customer a another name for selecting data ?

Comment: Good practice? Easier to convert to join?

Comment: an alias name is useful when there is a query involving more than one table.

Comment: When we have two or more tables which contains some same columns in that case to identify that which column belongs to which table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is so called alias. In your case, it is not required.
It is used to make querying easier when current names are inconvenient, ambigious or unknown (for group functions).

1. Example with ambigiousness in JOIN query. Let we have two tables:

**Users**

```
Id         int (PK)
Name       nvarchar(50)
```

**Books**

```
Id         int (PK)
UserId     int (FK)
Name       nvarchar(30)
```

Now, if you query both tables it will be ambigious because names are similar.
Here you can use aliases:

```
SELECT u.Id as UserId, u.Name as UserName, b.Name AS BookName
FROM Users AS u
INNER JOIN Books AS b
ON u.Id = b.UserId
```

You will get results:

```
| UserId | UserName | BookName |
--------------------------------
|   1    |   John   | Book123  |
|   2    |   Mark   | BookXYZ  |
etc...
```

In case you make a join on columns with the same name you will **have to** use aliases. Otherwise, it will be a wrong syntax.

```
INNER JOIN Books ON Id = Id ???
```

2. Group functions naming.
   For example, in queries with functions like.

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(*) as RowsCount FROM Users
   SELECT CONCAT(FirstName, " ", LastName, " ", MiddleName) as FullName FROM Users
   ```

you can use column alias to set a name and access it in the SQL reader or somewhere else.

3. It can be used for aliasing columns for convenience in some situations like this one:

   ```
   SELECT Id, HasUserEverBeenOnAHelpPage as Value FROM SomeTable
   ```

and get

```
| UserId | Value |
------------------
|   1    | true  |
|   2    | false |
```

instead of

```
| UserId | HasUserEverBeenOnAHelpPage |
---------------------------------------
|   1    | true                       |
|   2    | false                      |
```

It doesn't mean that it cannot be used in other situations. Sometimes, it is even used for code readabiliy and programmer's convenience:

```
SELECT u.Id,
       u.FirstName,
       u.LastName,
       ua.City,
       ua.AddressLine,
       ua.PostalCode,
       us.Language,
       us.IsCookieEnabled,
       lh.LastEnterDate
FROM Users as u
INNER JOIN UserAddresses as ua
ON ua.UserId = u.Id
INNER JOIN UserSettings as us,
ON us.UserId = u.Id
INNER JOIN LoginHistory as lh
ON lh.UserId = u.Id
```

In this case, the names are not ambigious and this query can be easily done without aliases. However, it is more convenient to work with them:

```
SELECT Users.Id,
       Users.FirstName,
       Users.LastName,
       UserAddresses.City,
       UserAddresses.AddressLine,
       UserAddresses.PostalCode,
       UserSettings.Language,
       UserSettings.IsCookieEnabled,
       LoginHistory.LastEnterDate
FROM Users
INNER JOIN UserAddresses
ON UserAddresses.UserId = Users.Id
INNER JOIN UserSettings
ON UserSettings .UserId = Users.Id
INNER JOIN LoginHistory
ON LoginHistory .UserId = Users.Id
```

Read more here:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp
[When to use SQL Table Alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198196/when-to-use-sql-table-alias)
http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/alias.php

Comment: Good answer. Strictly speak you can do a join without an alias if the column names match with the USING syntax. Can't say I am keen on it though.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it doesn't make any difference what so ever.
But when you have a query that uses multiple tables with joins, using an alias to the table name can make the query a lot more readable.
However, There is a naming convention that I use that will make aliasing table names completely useless (except when joining the same table more then once). [You can read about it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30132058/3094533)

from the performance point of view it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

When querying from a single table, using an alias is really not necessary (but it's good practice to get used to using it.)

When querying multiple tables, joining etc (specially when the same table is referenced multiple times), it is needed.

```
select * from Customer c join Email e on e.cust_id = c.id
```

Also, it is smart to use in nested selects, specially when multiple table share the same column name. This in order to be sure that you are referencing the column in the table you want to reference, and not another one.

Answer (score 0):

There can be more reasons to do so.

1. it can make a query more readable.
2. When you make a self join you have to give every table a unique name.

Answer (score 0):

These custom names (aliases) are useful when you're selecting a function, like

```
SELECT RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E, text, '').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY line)
             .GetClobVal(),
             ',') 
  FROM all_source t
 WHERE owner = 'QA_OWNER'
       AND NAME = 'PKG_PRJ_TEST_MANUAL';
```

this will return you a column with stupid and sometimes unpredictable name. You won't be able to use this as a subquery, for example. 
It's also nice to give custom names to columns in views you grant to another project users, for example. Your names may be meaningless to them.

---

In general - aliases improve readability.