# SQL - what's the best way to look up which table a column belongs to?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In a SQL Server environment, while maintaining a SQL query that involves multiple tables, often I'll need to figure out what what table a particular column belongs to.

Unfortunately, the notation in the query is not `TableName.ColumnName`, but just `ColumnName`.

Is there any way to look up what table the column is being pulled from, other than manually looking at column definitions for each table? I'm thinking something I can use either in an IDE (ie Management Studio) or a T-SQL statement... but I'm open to almost anything at this point.

One additional point: I need to do this locally, without pushing information over the network, or downloading additional tools outside SQL Management Studio... or Visual Studio.

Comment: Why is the notation `ColumnName` and not `TableName.ColumnName` or at least `TableAlias.ColumnName`? At the latest when two tables have the same columns you have to state the table.

Comment: [I never have this problem in my databases...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30132058/3094533)

Comment: No, there's no easy way. You are doing the job of the query parser. Not only that you have to scan the column names of all tables involved in the `JOINs` but to deal with column aliases, subquery, etc.

Comment: if it's a query that runs, the server is able to resolve all references to each of the columns.  have you tried looking at the query in the design view instead of the text?

Comment: @TimSchmelter the column names are not identical between tables. There are so many joins, outer applies to multiple tables, and functions etc... it's difficult to discern which table a column in the midst of everything.

Comment: With Intellisense it seems like reasonable feature.  If you mouse over it will tell you the datatype.   For any production query I try and use the full name for maintenance.  A lot of times people will post questions and you cannot answer property without knowing what table the column belongs to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can try both of this.

In Management Studio:

- Mark your query
- Right click
- Design Query in Editor

You'll get a graphical interface which will make it easier for you to see which column comes from which table.

Otherwise you can query (if you want to make it automatically) the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`:

```
SELECT c.COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as c
WHERE c.TABLE_CATALOG = N'YOURSCHEMA' AND c.TABLE_NAME = N'YOURTABLE'
```

Comment: Query Editor is sure is easier than hunting it down manually and it even uses the alias.   +1

Answer (score 1):

If you have Visual Studio installed, and can create a database project, you can use the refactor feature to add fully-qualified names to all SQL queries.  This will use aliases if they are employed, but will change the scripts so that every column at least has a reference value.

Scraping [the instructions from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193253%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to fully qualify all names that are contained in a .sql file in your solution

> In Solution Explorer, right-click the script file (.sql) that contains
>   names that you want to update, point to Refactor, and click
>   Fully-qualify Names.
>
> The Preview Changes dialog box appears and shows all names that will
>   be updated.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with databases deployed without using VS. Even creating a new database project, adding the query (as .sql file), and refactoring, yields only adding schema information, not the name of the parent. This happens if I refactor by right-clicking the database project or the script file.

Answer (score 0):

For simple queries, I've been able to use the [Instant SQL Formatter](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm) tool.

---

Paste your query into the editor, choose `List DB Object` in the Output dropdown, and click the `Format SQL` button. 
[image]

The page will output a list of tables and fields used by the query.  The fields will be qualified with the table name, as in your example above.

[image]

Comment: Good idea... however I'm working with data I don't want to push over the internet. I'll edit my question to clarify. Honestly I didn't think about a solution outside of my workstation.

Comment: That's a fair point, if you had to connect it to data; I've used this to just parse SQL code, which doesn't generally contain any sensitive information.